# Does "next highest" mean higher or lower?

Tags: american-english, comparisons

A friend of mine recently argued about an interpretation of some by-laws. Specifically, what "next highest" meant. My interpretation: if you have roles A, B, C, where A is the highest role, then B is the next highest. He disagreed, saying that the "next highest" should be HIGHER, not lower. I was sure mine was the common usage, but doing a little Googling I do see instances of his approach--saying, for example, that after third place, the next highest is second place. Which is correct?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/next-best http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/the-next-best-thing http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-nextbest.html HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  That person who commented that "If you came third, then the next highest is second" (http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1300562) is wrong, as is your friend.

Here is a good example of the usage of "next highest": http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Highest+bidder

```
In judicial sales, where the highest bidder is unable to pay, it is said the sheriff may offer the property to the next highest [bidder]
```

Comment: This seems a perfectly correct answer to me and I am mystified as to why someone has down-voted it.

Comment: It's certainly the usual meaning. But I was amused to find that a Google search for "next highest" turned up _Best bet to be the next highest building in the world is the 800-meter or so Burj Dubai in the United Arab Emirates_. Though I admit to dropping the scare quotes. // It depends on the cohesiveness of 'next highest' of course: is 'next' modifying 'highest' or the rest of the noun phrase coming after 'next'.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing.

It mostly depends on context -- if the "highest" has just been mentioned then "next highest" almost certainly means the one *below* but adjacent to the highest.  This is also the standard assumption there's been no prior mention of an adjacent element.

On the other hand, if one says "next higher" (not "high**est**) that very likely means the element that is *above* but adjacent to the element just mentioned (even if prior element was the lowest).  If no prior element has been mentioned then it's kind of up in the air.

And "next lower/next lowest" are even vaguer -- you don't hear "next lowest" or "next lower" nearly as much as "next highest" or "next higher", and there are fewer "usual assumptions".